# Configuration file missing after successful SSRS migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security, migration, ssrs

Getting the [backup of all SSRS databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118537/22336) including [compressing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3125/22336) and [encrypting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149797/22336) can be straight forward.

However, when planning a complete solution for SQL Server Reporting services backup, following the link below can be more demanding.

[Backup and Restore Operations for Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/backup-and-restore-operations-for-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15)

Among other things, including the [encryption keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-encryption-keys-back-up-and-restore-encryption-keys?view=sql-server-ver15), [master keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/backup-and-restore-operations-for-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15), [Backing Up the Configuration Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/backup-and-restore-operations-for-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15#backing-up-the-configuration-files)

```
Reporting Services uses configuration files to store application settings. 
You should back up the files when you first configure the server and after you deploy any custom extensions. 

Files to back up include:
```

1. Rsreportserver.config
2. Rssrvpolicy.config
3. Rsmgrpolicy.config
4. Reportingservicesservice.exe.config
5. Web.config for the Report Server ASP.NET application
6. Machine.config for ASP.NET

QUESTION:

I have just installed SQL Server Reporting Services, [migrated all databases and reports](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68161/22336), [including all folder permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/260271/22336),  from a previous server (sql server 2008),and [all is working fine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/195019/22336).

However, on the backup strategy, I cannot find some of the `.config` files that are required to backup.
The file that is missing is `Rsmgrpolicy.config`

Why is this file missing?

```
cls
# PowerShell script to list the DLL files under the system32 folder
$Dir = get-childitem "C:\Program Files\" -recurse
# $Dir |get-member
$List = $Dir | where {$_.extension -eq ".config" -and $_.name -like "*rs*"}
$List | format-table Directory, name
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working fine, including the encryption and all the security, 
so as the file is not there, I will not need to include it on my backups.

this link below shows where all the configuration files should be:

[Reporting Services Configuration Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-configuration-files?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

> Install Paths   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSRSxx.MSSQLSERVER  (where xx is the MS SQL version number)
>   or   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS
>   depending on the SSRS version

There it also explains the role of the `RSMgrPolicy.config` file.

> Stores the code access security policies for the web portal. For more
>   information about this file, 
>   see
>   [Using Reporting Services Security Policy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/secure-development/using-reporting-services-security-policy-files?view=sql-server-ver15).

Looking at this second link, that explains the Security policy, I understood that the file `RSMgrPolicy.config` was not needed in my setup. It was not clear in the first documentation but all is good now.